# Are there any licensing costs involved in using BlackBerry Maps API

Tags: blackberry, maps

Are there any licensing costs to be paid for commercial applications that use the BlackBerry Maps API or registered developers can use them in any commercial applications being developed by them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the "RIM Base Map Product Offerings" described [here](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/legal.jsp) under Section 1, then there is no cost. In section 2(f) however, it says that if want to use “Enhanced map APIs”, then you would have to enter a license agreement with TANA. More than likely if you have access to these APIs then there should be a license in one or all of the files, and probably instructions that come with the API detailing how to enter a license agreement with TANA.

Short answer: You can use the map API for free if you are using the basic APIs. If you want to use the more advanced features provided in the “Enhanced map APIs”, then read the documentation specific to those APIs. It could be that there is an implied license in the API.

Answer (score 2):

There are no cost related to using most of the BlackBerry API.

I have no document that proves it, but where I work we sell application that use Blackberry Maps, and we didn't bought any license.

The user already paid for the device which include the Technology, so the developper dosen't need to pay to use the API.

Except for the API that need to be [signed](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/codekeys.jsp).

You should probably read the [license](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/legal.jsp) on RIM website.